# How to draw NOT diagram using circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am trying to recreate the following diagram:

[image]

So, far, starting with the NOT gate, I have the following:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
  \draw
    (0, 0) node[nand port] (a) {}
    (a.in 1) -- ++(-5mm,0) |- (a.in 2)
    (a.out) -- ++(5mm,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

Which looks like:

[image]

I want to add the line on the right hand side (with the black circle where the lines join).

I would also like to add a black circle to the start of the input line and end of the output line (not on the original diagram).

Comment: Try `\draw (0,0) node[nand port] (a) {} (-2,0) -| node[circ,midway]{} (a.in 1) -| (a.in 2);`.

Comment: @ferahfeza Thanks, that works. Any idea how to get the circle on the end of the output line?

Comment: @kentrid  have alook at the answer below

Comment: @ferahfeza Is there any way, using this method, to have the input length 5mm, so it is the same length as the output?

Comment: If you use `\circuitikz{logic ports=ieee}` the shape will match your example much more. For the pin length, look at page 118-119 of the manual...

Comment: And if you want exactly 5mm, just suppress the pins and use the border anchors (same pages in the manual).

Comment: @Rmano Could you give an example on how I would make it 5mm, using the code from the first comment?

Answer (score 1):

for the black circle use

```
[short,-*]
```

[image]

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw
    (0, 0) node[nand port] (a) {}
    (a.in 1) -- ++(-5mm,0) |- (a.in 2)
    (a.out) to[short,-*](5mm,0);
        
\end{circuitikz}
```

and if you require a blank circle at the output side instead of a filled circle
use

```
[short,-o]
```

[image]